# CollectionView as a Subview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, frame, subview

CollectionView as a Subview in Swift

I am try to insert a very simple collectionView as a Subview but cannot get a right frame. What am I doing wrong? Could you help me please?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    setupCollectionView()

}

func setupCollectionView() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: testView.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    testView.addSubview(collectionView)

}
```

}

Comment: call setupCollectionView() into viewDidLoad()

Comment: try `testView.bounds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func setupCollectionView() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, testView.frame.size.width, height: testView.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    testView.addSubview(collectionView)
    testView.clipsToBounds=true

    }
```

Problem is "testView.frame" that. testview frame x and y point not 0

Comment: Thank you! That work with one small correction: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: testView.frame.size.width, height: testView.frame.size.height),

Comment: @Roman you should accept and upvote the answer if it helped and resolved your issue!